# If a Maven artifact is not in central repository and local, how to automatically search which public repository to add in pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

I am new to maven and find that some artifacts are not on Maven central repository, so I need to manually add repository 's id and url in `pom.xml`. It's relatively easy if I were the original developer of the project, but hard as a maintainer.

For example, I get [a Maven project](https://github.com/cyrilcc/org.openhab.binding.rflink/blob/master/pom.xml) from GitHub. The project has an dependency on `org.openhab.addons.bundles:org.openhab.addons.reactor.bundles:3.2.0-SNAPSHOT`, which is not on Maven central repository.
What I do is Google `org.openhab.addons.bundles  org.openhab.addons.reactor.bundles` to try finding which public repository should I add in `pom.xml`.
Like

```xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>openhab</id>
    <url>https://openhab.jfrog.io/openhab/libs-release/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

My question is that given a Maven artifact's coordinate, how can I **programmatically** find which repository should I add in `pom.xml`?

Thank you.

Comment: *My question is that given a Maven artifact's coordinate, how can I programmatically find which repository should I add in pom.xml* Short answer, you can't. You'll need to setup some kind of custom artifact system and pass maven the new system's URL

Comment: Setup a repository manager and configure the different repos there...